# warning: configuration file not found

Tags: hyperref, captions, warnings, epstopdf

I get 2 warnings with regard to configuration file not being found. I think these might have something to do with the other 2 warnings that are reported before these in the log.
They are not causing any trouble yet and the output looks good, but why am I getting these and how can I solve it?

```
Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.

Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than 'pdftex.def' are not supported.

Package caption Warning: Configuration file caption.cfg not found on input line 293.

Package subfig Warning: Configuration file subfig.cfg not found on input line 297.
```

N.B. I am using the MikTex compiler and the TeXnicCenter GUI. They are set to download the required packages. I have tried both `LaTeX -> PS -> PDF` and `LaTeX -> DVI -> PDF` and it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that also produces these warnings, so we can have a look at it. You could try running normal pdfLaTeX on your file instead of LaTeX and a conversion - that of course only works if you don't need any of the features of DVI output.

Comment: You are passing the option "config" to the packages and so they try to load a cfg and inform you that they failed.